# Refresh UI Tab Bar Controller state on Log out/Log in

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have Initial Root Controller as UITab Bar Controller. On log out and log_in the state of the UI Tab Bar controller doesn't change nor the data /views of Tab bar items.  It shows the old state till the time I rebuild it.
On log out action I am using perform segue only. DO I need to take care any other things. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have a tabBar with 3 controllers [ profile , content , other ] , and you logged out in the profile , so you need to remove the profile tab , you can do this

```
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers.remove(at:0)
```

when you login again do

```
let profile = ///// init the vc
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers.insert(profile,at:0)
```

The idea is that you have the `viewControllers` that contains all the tabs , so you can play with it as you want , BTW note if you have

> firstVC-----------> segue -------> secondVC

and want to return to firstVc , you should dimiss secondVC not make a segue back